# How to change the queue priority in BitTorrent?

Tags: windows, bittorrent

[image: BitTorrent queue screenshot]

I am using this BitTorrent 7.6 and I have many downloads in my queue.

I just want to change the queue order (marked in red) instantly but the process is manually and time consuming  is their any way by which I can do this instantly.

Is their any options to do this or any 3rd party tools has to be installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In uTorrent, you can use the shortcut keys on multiple selected items to move the bunch up and down rather quickly. If I remember correctly, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>.

Maybe BitTorrent also has a similar keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to do this with the Bittorrent client. However with the [uTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/) client you can easily adjust queue priority for items. I apologize if switching clients is not a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the 2 clients are almost identical.

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure that they are not identical, not even close. There is a great variation in Bittorrent client features. But I could be wrong, I have not used the default Bittorrent client in several years; perhaps they aimed for feature parity with uTorrent.

Comment: [BitTorrent Inc. acquired µTorrent several years ago. The µTorrent code is the base for the official BitTorrent client.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utorrent) You can already tell they're pretty much identical by looking at the screenshot.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that. Thank you, sorry for the error.

Answer (score -1):

On a Mac, the shortcut is CTRL + OPTION + Arrow Key Up or Down